# Password field regex using jquery val().match

Tags: jquery, regex

Building a regex to exclude characters /, \, ' and " from a password field.

```
$(':password').keyup(function () {

    if ($(this).val().match(/^['"\\\/]+$/)) {
        $(this).css("border", "5px solid red");
    } else {
        $(this).css("border", "5px solid green");
    };

});
```

The border around the input field should go red if the password field contains any illegal characters. What seems to happen is that it only does this when the field contains exclusively illegal characters. Entering a legal character amongst many illegal ones makes the string acceptable again.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/8qLr6/8/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8qLr6/10/

try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you used the special characters (`^` and `$`) to denote the start, and end, of string as part of the match (thereby matching the entirety of the string); if you remove those then it matches any 'illegal' character at any point; this gives the regular expression:

```
/['"\\\/]+/
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8qLr6/9/).

You could also tidy up, for conciseness, to give:

```
$(':password').keyup(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css('border', function(){
        return '5px solid ' + ($this.val().match(/['"\\\/]+/) ? 'red' : 'green');
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8qLr6/11/).

Incidentally, where it's available it's a little more efficient to use `input[type="password"]` rather than `:password`; this is because the former can, where it's available, be passed off to the browser's native `document.querySelectorAll()`, rather than using Sizzle to parse the document (using a jQuery/Sizzle-specific selector).

References:

- [Regular Expressions (Mozilla Developer Network)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).